# how to skip an activity once its not needed? android

Tags: android, if-statement

im doing a starting setup settings thing for my app and i was wondering how i can get it to skip the sign up page once they have already entered once? an if statement would be the thing I thought but im not so good with if statements in android so could anyone point me in the direction for a solution?

Comment: I'm confused how you are not good with 'if' statements. They are one of the most basic building blocks. And the language in 'Java'. I would invest some serious time reading about programming before going forward with your project.

Comment: it has been answered and being a visual basic programmer myself makes java 'if' statements seem unnecessarily complicated and if something useful isn't being said don't say it.

Comment: good luck being this rude in the real world yourself. get a life

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store a value in `SharedPreferences` (e.g. `boolean loggedIn=true`) once the login data has been entered and saved. Then every time you start your app get the value from `SharedPreferences` and decide whether to show the login-window (`loggedIn==false`) or not (`loggedIn==true`).

Answer (score 3):

I've done this by having an Activity with no UI as my startup activity which checks for the existence of a prefernce setting and then launches either the sign up activity or the main activity depending on whether or not the preference setting exists.

In the androidmanifest you can register your activity with no UI using something like this (if I remember correctly):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

After launching your chosen activity you need to call finish() in the UI-less activity

Comment: This is also very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should maintain a boolean and save it in SharedPreference and check it there and perform your task accordingly.......

Comment: thank you but iDroid just got n there before you.

Comment: does not matter .... you got the solution...